# Consume wsHttpBinding with PHP Soap Client

Tags: php, web-services, wcf, soap, .net-3.5

is there a way to use `wsHttpBinding` with the PHP Soap Client? It did not work on my website on the first  attempts. I had to change the connection to `basicHttpBinding`.

The main reason to do this is that (as I understand) the `wsHttpBinding` uses newer Soap Standards and has some kind of security implemented. Also the order of the response should be the same as the order of the requests.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`basicHttpBinding` use SOAP 1.1 and `wsHttpBinding` use SOAP 1.2

By default SoapClient use SOAP 1.1 but you can modify that.

```
$wsdl = "...url_to_your_wsdl...";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know PHP Soap Client does not support entire WS standard (WS-Security in particular). You should try to use some 3rd party frameworks like this:

http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

If you configure WsHttpBinding to have no security or transport security then it should be possible. the desired soap will be simple and you can create it even by concatenating strings. otherwise I don't think php supports the newset security standards.